# How to show total number of elements in a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am using following code to show the total number of years of specific league, but it shows 1 for each year.

For example,  Spanish Primera Division has three years but it shows 1,1,1 instead of 3.

I have used `count($object);` and `sizeof($object);` but don't get desired results.

[image: See the image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class=" reds clearfix"; style="width: 50%;">
    <ul id="test">
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $fixture_query->have_posts() ) : $fixture_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
            $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
            $terms_session = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'session' ); ?>

            <?php foreach ($terms_session as $object) {?>
                <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"> <?php echo  $object->name; ?></li>
                <?php
                //echo count($object); // output 2
                echo sizeof($object);
                // echo count($object->name); 
                ?>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it tagged with js???

Comment: It  can also  be solved with js. Isn't it?

Comment: You may need echo sizeof($terms_session); ...

Comment: Nope. JS is user side. You are counting in server side code

Comment: Which part of your code is supposed to produce the desired **total**?

Comment: li part, please see the image.

Comment: fyi  sizeof() is an alias for count()  but you probably do NOT want to to have that line within the foreach loop  Instead do `count($terms_session)` BEFORE the foreach loop.

Comment: Could you please proved it as answer as I am new to PHP? @ Duane Lortie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to show the total number of sessions inside the foreach loop.

Based on your code, you can calculate total number of sessions as

`$total_sessions = count($terms_session);`

Now you can easily use this variable inside the foreach loop as

```
<?php
    foreach ($terms_session as $object) {?>
        <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"> <?php echo  $object->name; ?></li>
        <?php 
        echo $total_sessions;
        ?>
<?php }
?>
```

Here is the complete code with changes, see the comments for additions.

```
<div class=" reds clearfix"; style="width: 50%;">
  <ul id="test">

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $fixture_query->have_posts() ) : $fixture_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php
      $champion_team = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'football_league_team_name', true );
      $terms_competition = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' );
      $terms_session = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'session' ); 
      // Calculate the total number of sessions
      $total_sessions = count($terms_session);
      ?>
      <?php
      foreach ($terms_session as $object) {?>
      <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"> <?php echo  $object->name; ?></li>
      <?php 
        // Display the total number of sessions
        echo $total_sessions;
      ?>
      <?php }
      ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo count($terms_session);//this give all count of elements
foreach ($terms_session as $object) { ?>
    <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"> <?php echo $object->name; ?></li>
    <?php
    //echo count($object); // output 2
    echo sizeof($object);
    // echo count($object->name); 
    ?>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for what this code is doing and how it directly answers the question.